# data is not binding in listbox

Tags: c#, .net

Data is present in `lstListSource` but is not binding.

```
objLogEntries.Message.AppendLine("Bind ListBox with list started...");
listBoxControl.DataSource = lstListSource;
listBoxControl.DataTextField = strDataTextField;
listBoxControl.DataValueField = strDateValueField;
listBoxControl.DataBind();
objLogEntries.Message.AppendLine("Bind ListBox with list ended...");
Log.WriteTraceLog(objLogEntries);
```

It is throwing an exception: `lstlnkSRAlias'(ID of listbox) has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items`

Comment: DataValueField must be set to a value that exists in lstListSource. This exception is telling me that DataValueField is being set to a value that does not

Comment: @Amir, i am not getting... data is coming in lstListSource

Comment: what is the value assign for `strDataTextField` & `strDateValueField` ?

Comment: There should problem in DataTextField and DataValueField which set by you. It should name of the property on the object you are trying to bind.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the `DataTextField` or `DataValueField` correctly. It should be set to the name of the property on the object you are trying to bind to. Something like:

```
listBoxControl.DataSource = lstListSource;
listBoxControl.DataTextField = "Text";
listBoxControl.ValueMember = "Value";
listBoxControl.DataBind();
```

Also, if the binding is getting refreshed try clearing the list before setting the data source:

```
listBoxControl.Items.Clear();
listBoxControl.SelectedIndex = -1;
listBoxControl.SelectedValue = null;
listBoxControl.ClearSelection();
listBoxControl.DataSource = lstListSource;
```

There's a full example in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: every thing is perfect but the data is not binding only.

Comment: When does the exception get thrown? Can you post the data in `lstListSource`?